# NetCDF spatially merging to global data

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate, nco

Currently I use global precipitation (ppt) and potential evapotranspiration (pet) data to calculate SPEI. As I have limited hardware resources, I divided global ppt and ppt data into 32 parts, each file covering 45x45deg and contains 756 data - monthly from 1958-2020 (tile01.nc, tile02.nc, ... tile32.nc)

- For example to do this, I use `cdo sellonlatbox,-180,-135,45,90 in.nc out.nc` or `ncks -d lat,45.,90. -d lon,-180.,-135. in.nc -O out.nc`
- As required by SPEI script, I reorder and fixed the dimension from `time,lat,lon` to `lat,lon,time` using `ncpdq` and `ncks`.
- From the SPEI output, I got the output in `lat,lon,time`. So I did reorder the dimension so that it becomes `time,lat,lon` using `ncpdq`.
- Each tile SPEI output covering 45x45deg and contains 756 SPEI data - monthly from 1958-2020

Finally I need to merge all the output together (32 files) into one, so I will get the global SPEI output. I have try to use `cdo mergegrid` but the result is not what I expected. Is there any command from `cdo` or `nco` to solve this problem that has function similar to `gdal_merge` if we are dealing with geoTIFF format?

Below is the example of the SPEI output

[image: panoply]

UPDATE

I managed to merge all the data using `cdo collgrid` as suggested by Robert below. And here's the result:

[image: spei]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you want to use CDO's distgrid and collgrid methods for this.

First, run this:

```
cdo distgrid,4,8 in.nc obase
```

That will split the files up the way you want them.

Then do the post-processing necessary on the files.

Then use collgrid to merge the files:

```
cdo collgrid obase* out.nc
```

Potentially you can just use collgrid in place of mergegrid in your present work flow, depending on how you have split the files up.

Comment: Thank you, it's worked and this is new for me. I don't realize the `distgrid` before, so I use `sellonlatbox` and create a list for 32 file. :(

Comment: I  didn't  know those commands either ! good answer

Comment: very useful commands indeed